# How valuable is the RSA private key in kubernetes for an attacker?

Tags: security, kubernetes, rsa

I am currently playing with kubernetes and read about a security issue (cve-2018-18264) where it was possible to gain unauthorized access to the dashboards secrets (the certificate plus the RSA private key).

Now I am wondering how valuable the RSA private key and the certificate is for an attacker especially in kubernetes? Can someone tell me about?

How about if Diffie-Hellman is used for key exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said on [CVE-2018-18264: Kubernetes Dashboard TLS Certificate Leak](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/blog/cve-2018-18264/).

> ### Description
>
> Kubernetes Dashboard before 1.10.1 allows attackers to bypass authentication and use Dashboard’s Service Account for reading secrets within the cluster.

So if You deployed an app, lets take this [Mysql Wordpress deployment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/blob/master/cloudsql/mysql_wordpress_deployment.yaml), attacker might gain access to your DB login and password.

Also if You are using secrets as authentication between application, attacker might use [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack.

[DH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) is no longer considered as secure.

> ...
>   However, research published in October 2015 suggests that the parameters in use for many DH Internet applications at that time are not strong enough to prevent compromise by very well-funded attackers, such as the security services of large governments.[[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#cite_note-imperfectfs-4)
>
> Paper talking about this is [Imperfect Forward Secrecy: How Diffie-Hellman Fails in Practice](https://weakdh.org/imperfect-forward-secrecy-ccs15.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, but the RSA key has no effect on the DH. DH is insecure by itself, right?

Comment: This is not about RSA, but about [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) being stored in k8s.